# ManyToMany how to remove child from parent list

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, cascade

How to remove object from list without removing that parent object in many to many relationship?
I have ticketEntity with set of offenceEntity:

```
public class TicketEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "offences_in_tickets",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offence_id"))
    private Set<OffenceEntity> offences;
    }
```

and OffenceEntity with set of TicketEntity:

```
public class OffenceEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="offences", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TicketEntity> tickets;
}
```

Should I change cascade type? Now when I remove one of OffenceEntity from database I am removing TicketEntity too, but I would like to delete only Offence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "parent" or "child" is, or what you mean by "removing from list", as there is no list in your examples. If you want an answer to your questions, please invest more time in writing up a proper question and try to re-read the question with the mindset of someone who doesn't work on this problem. Maybe ask a colleague if the question is immediately understandable before posting this.

Having said that, I can only assume that "parent" refers to `TicketEntity` and "child" refers to `OffenceEntity`.
So if you want to remove the many-to-many relationship between two such objects, you simply have to load the `TicketEntity` and remove the respective `OffenceEntity` from the `offences` set e.g. like this:

```
entityManager.find(TicketEntity.class, ticketId)
    .getOffences()
    .remove(
        entityManager.find(OffenceEntity.class, offenceId)
    );
```